# High CPU Usage By Simple Query SQL Server 2019 Std

Tags: php, performance, cpu-usage, linked-server, sql-server-2019

i am in need or help. Below are my developer query for web display purpose. This query basically only return 3 column of data but it use high cpu when doing so.

````
select aa.x aD8,ba.x aD6,ca.x aD5,d.x TOTAL
            From 
                (select COUNT(p.IDN) x  from P_Tracking p, DPI d 
                    where p.IDN=d.IDN and p.IDVer=d.IDVer and p.WIPFlag = 1 and 
                    p.VType = 1 and p.WIPCode between 'W4010' and 'W4050' 
                    and d.ModelCode='D8'
                    and p.IDN 
                    not in (select IDN from PISSERVER.PIS.dbo.CustomsExcise))aa,
                
                (select COUNT(p.IDN) x  from P_Tracking p, DPI d 
                    where p.IDN=d.IDN and p.IDVer=d.IDVer and p.WIPFlag = 1 and 
                    p.VType = 1 and p.WIPCode between 'W4010' and 'W4050' 
                    and d.ModelCode='D6'
                    and p.IDN 
                    not in (select IDN from PISSERVER.PIS.dbo.CustomsExcise))ba,

                (select COUNT(p.IDN) x  from P_Tracking p, DPI d 
                    where p.IDN=d.IDN and p.IDVer=d.IDVer and p.WIPFlag = 1 and 
                    p.VType = 1 and p.WIPCode between 'W4010' and 'W4050' 
                    and d.ModelCode='D5'
                    and p.IDN 
                    not in (select IDN from PISSERVER.PIS.dbo.CustomsExcise))ca,
                
                (select COUNT(p.IDN)x from P_Tracking p, DPI d 
                where p.IDN=d.IDN and p.IDVer=d.IDVer and p.WIPFlag = 1 
                and p.VType = 1 and p.WIPCode between 'W4010' and 'W4075')d``` 

[From Activity Monitor of Recent Expensive Queries for this query][1]

This code is in a sql server 'OSMServer' while the linkedserver is 'PISSERVER'

This query is running from php files which be used by 200 users average. when users spikes, the cpu may reach 100%.

How do we improve this query performance? I believe this is traditional way of sql query but i am not sure how else to improve this.  

Because we also have given the sql indexes, my last resort was to improve the query.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZAoc.png
````

Comment: Based on your giant query and no schema, my first guess is to look into putting indexes on your data

Comment: I have put the indexes recommended by SQL server before deploy into live production environment. But it still causing high cpu usage.

Comment: Can you change from `CROSS JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`? Like:
`from P_Tracking p INNER JOIN DPI d ON p.IDN=d.IDN and p.IDVer=d.IDVer WHERE`